# Using BLE RSSI value for connect-by-proximity

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

we are creating a system in which a embedded BLE peripheral will connect and send data to an App on an iPad.  There may be multiple peripherals in the vicinity, so the App user has to specify which to connect to by selecting from a list of advertising peripherals.  (This is done in-App, which is supported by iOS BLE.)

My question is, can we build in a feature to connect to a peripheral that is *very* close using the RSSI?  The RSSI (relative signal strength) is provided to our App as a parameter from all advertising peripherals.  We could test to see what this level is for a peripheral that is, say 6 inches away vs 5 feet away, and then auto-connect to a peripheral (that is of the right "type") that is close.  This will allow the user to move the peripheral close to the iPad to connect, rather than selecting from a list.

This would be slick, but I don't know if RSSI signal is too unreliable for this purpose or if there are other gotchas.  Certainly people must have tried to use this data this way, but I'm not seeing many reports of this, good or bad.  I have read that different vendors will report the RSSI value different ways, but we will *only* be connecting our App to this particular device, so we can tune it for this exact combination of hardware.

Thanks very much for any thoughts.  Has anybody tried this, and has it worked for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSSI is signal strength and signal strength usually correlates with distance.  However, the assumption made is all devices are transmitting with the same amount of power.  If you're using a variety of devices you may run into issues due to different transmit powers.  I guess you need to find out how much difference there is between devices' transmit power and how much that affects RSSI at different distances.  There may not be much difference in power since BLE is intended for lower power usage.

Also, I'm pretty sure RSSI changes over distance are not linear.  So it may be easier to distinguish between 2 devices at 1ft and 3 ft then 2 devices at 6 ft and 12 ft.  I'm not really sure of the details, though, and again that's assume both devices are transmitting at the same power level.  If you do some searching you might be able to find the formula used for iBeacon distance calculations based on RSSI.

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful.